# In C# convert Json string to Json Object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I got Json file on local machine that I need to deserialize into class object Products. I am intended to Newtonsoft.Json library since it is console application. I am implemented following code, that I can see jsonString but not doing something right JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(st)???

Also my json has product array with nested record!

### json

```
{
 "products": [
   {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "red apple",
    "pricePerUnit ": "1.53"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "name": "green walnut",
     "pricePerUnit ": "0.25"
   },
   {
     "id": "3",
     "name": "avocado",
     "pricePerUnit ": "0.33"
   }
 ]
}
```

### json converting class

```
var stream = File.OpenText("C:\\Products.json");
string st = stream.ReadToEnd();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(st);
```

### Product class

```
public class ProductEntity
{
    public List<Products> products { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string pricePerUnit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You try to deseralize a Products object. However, your Json data does not represent a Products object. (Pay attention and follow the Json syntax in your Json data!) It rather contains a Json object with a "products" property which has an Json Array which contains multiple objects with each of those matching your Products class. (You already have another class that matches this structure: ProductEntity. Try deserializing your Json data as an ProductEntity object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remodel your POCO:

```
public class ProductEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string PricePerUnit { get; set; }
}
```

And then de-serialize it as follows:

```
internal class Solution1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = @"
        {
             'products': [
               {
                'id': '1',
                'name': 'red apple',
                'price': '1.53'
               },
               {
                 'id': '2',
                 'name': 'green walnut',
                 'price': '0.25'
               },
               {
                 'id': '3',
                 'name': 'avocado',
                 'price': '0.33'
               }
             ]
          }";

        ProductEntity result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductEntity>(str);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that pricePerUnit does not exist in the json context, you need to use a data annotation to specify that you want price to be interpreted as pricePerUnit

```
public class Products
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price")]
    public string pricePerUnit { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

Also as gonzo posted you are not deserializing correctly, you would need a List or deserialize it as ProductEntity.

1. `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductEntity>(st);`
2. `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Products>>(st);`

Both of them are correct, but since you have already have the ProductEntity I suggest using the first one. Another minor thing class names should be singular

Comment: While this is indeed a problem, that is only one minor-ish problem. The "bigger" problem is that Toxic tries to deserialize a Products object, but the Json data obviously does not match the Products class declaration...

Comment: His first problem is that the JSON is a `ProductEntity`, not a `Products`.

Comment: @elgonzo yeah i seen your comment thats why i edited my answer

Comment: var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductEntity>(st);